What was the order of events, by hour, for each of the first 5 days of creation?
B"H
There's a maamar chazal (Avos DRebbi Noson 1:8) that tells us the specific order of events on the sixth day by hour.. One hour, Hashem gathered Adam's dust from around the world, another hour Adam called names to everything etc., another hour he ate from the tree etc etc
Are there any other commentators or references to what the specific order of events were on the other days of creation, by the hour?
For example, on the first day Rashi says first the heavens and earth and everything in them was created in a general way (and only later were the specific objects placed where they need to go etc.), then hashem made the water, then light and darkness, then separated between them etc.
But is there any indication as to what specific hours of the day hashem did these things, or was it all at once, and the rest of the day was just nothing new etc?
Similarly for the other days, the separation of the upper and lower waters, the emergence of dry land, the sprouting of vegetation, the placement of the sun moon and stars etc etc,
How long did each these acts take? What time of the day did they happen, right at the beginning of the day, at sunrise, or since midnight, or in the afternoon etc?

See for example the Rabbeinu Bahya specifically on the creation of man
